# how to apply If statements to my java gui textbox

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

I need that if statement which will reverse what the user enters to be applied on my jt text field but whatever I try, it won't work!

```
public class MorseCodeFinch extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JTextField jt = new JTextField(15);
    JButton jb = new JButton("Enter");
    JLabel jl = new JLabel();
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")

    public MorseCodeFinch(){

        String s = "";
            if( s.contains(",") ) {
                s = s.replaceAll(",","");
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(s);
                builder.reverse();
                System.out.println(builder);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
```

Comment: In real time or after they've finished typing?

Comment: well it the users data is used later on in the program effecting the outcome so straight away before it gets pasted down the array.

Comment: please remove the invalid code if it is not in your class. the { after String s and the ' after the method block.

Comment: why would this help the code?

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown it was valid, but it just useless

Comment: Ok I removed it but could you help me so the jt box is using the if statement?!

Comment: @Rafa I didn't see a closing brace to the block starting after the String.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown by referring to the code indentation, method `MorseCodeFinch()` is the one that doesn't have closing bracket. which is, I guest OP didn't post the full code

Comment: no there's pages more code! i just need help on that bit... anyone?!